# mysql query issue : Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, oscommerce

I have use php5.3 and already done with "`SET NAMES utf8`";
I am using oscommerce.

PHP code:

```
tep_db_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$result = tep_db_fetch_array(tep_db_query("select customers_email_address from  customers where customers_firstname='" . tep_db_input($fname) . "' AND customers_lastname='" . tep_db_input($lname) . "'"));
```

my query and error are following:

> 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
>
> select customers_email_address from customers where customers_firstname='Robert' AND customers_lastname='OÂ˜iaas'
>
> [TEP STOP]

Tabel structure is below. I can not update database structure

```
--
-- Table structure for table `customers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_gender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customers_firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `customers_lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `customers_dob` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customers_email_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customers_id`),
  KEY `idx_customers_email_address` (`customers_email_address`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18109 ;
```

Comment: Change the default charset of the table

Comment: Thanks and Yes, then working, but i can't. 
because already some joins are implemented latin1 to latin1.
Have any solution in which no need to change table structure. like mysql function or php function?

Comment: Then cast one thing as the other thing - but it's much better if you can make everything utf8.

Comment: yes, i am thinking on that. but it is the big change. some value may be convert.

Comment: I fear you have a worse problem...  Let's make sure the data is even stored as latin1 -- run `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM ...` to see if you get 2 bytes where you should get 1 character.  (And show the results.)

Comment: What was `'OÂ˜iaas'` supposed to be?

Comment: To read the excel file and then pass values in query. means `'OÂ˜iaas' `comes from excel sheet